# Why does iPhone backup setting keep changing to iCloud after backup?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

I backup my iPhone (iOS 14.6) to my Mac (macOS Big Sur) using the Finder. I just want the backup to be on my Mac and not on iCloud, Finder gives you the following options:

- Backup your most important data on your iPhone to iCloud
- Back up all the data on your iPhone to this Mac

I want the backup to be on my Mac and **not** on iCloud, but after click "Apply" or do the backup, the option selection jumps right back to "backup to iCloud".

iCloud backup is also turned off on the iPhone.
Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Comment: when you select the local option do you click the "Apply" button immediately afterwards?

Comment: Sounds like a display issue in Finder - does iCloud Backup *ever* turn on on the iPhone? If it doesn't, then it's off

Comment: It's off on the iPhone.